# Python request using ast.literal_eval error Invalid syntax?

Tags: python, json, parsing, http, httprequest

i am new to python and trying to get request data using ast.literal_eval resulting in "invalid syntax" error.

It prints data i send that is format like,

```
192.156.1.0,8181,database,admin,12345
```

In python i display it but get error while reading it my code is,

```
    print str(request.body.read())
    datas = request.body.read()
    data=ast.literal_eval(datas)
    dbname = data['dbname']
    username = data['uname']
    ip = data['ip']
    port = data['port']
    pwd = data['pwd']
```

Invalid syntax error on line **data=ast.literal_eval(datas)**

How to resolve it suggestion will be appreciable

Thanks

Comment: this dosent look like python expression

Comment: @Hackaholic it is part of python service and error i am getting at line i mentioned.

Comment: `192.156.1.0,8181,database,admin,12345` is not a python expression

Comment: print str(request.body.read()) code print line you mentioned above.

Comment: Have you tried not calling `read` twice? If `request.body` is a file-like object, `read` isn't a pure function; calling it twice will give you an empty string on the second call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change this:

```
192.156.1.0,8181,database,admin,12345
```

to this:

```
>>> a = "['192.156.1.0',8181,'database','admin',12345]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
['192.156.1.0', 8181, 'database', 'admin', 12345]
```

ast.literal_eval

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating
> arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

you can try like this:

```
>>> a='192.156.1.0,8181,database,admin,12345'
>>> a = str(map(str,a.split(',')))
>>> a
"['192.156.1.0', '8181', 'database', 'admin', '12345']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
['192.156.1.0', '8181', 'database', 'admin', '12345']
```

your code will look like this:

```
data=ast.literal_eval(str(map(str,datas.split(','))))
```

Comment: 192.156.1.0,8181,database,admin,12345 is comming from http POST how to change it into string.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like

```
dbname, username, ip, port, pwd = request.body.read().split(',')
```

**Test**

```
>>> str = "192.156.1.0,8181,database,admin,12345"
>>> dbname , username , ip, port ,pwd = str.split(',')
>>> dbname
'192.156.1.0'
>>> username
'8181'
>>> ip
'database'
>>> port
'admin'
>>> pwd
'12345'
```

Comment: cant do like this any one can inject malicious code

Comment: 192.156.1.0,8181,database,admin,12345 commin from http POST how to convert it into string ?

Comment: `str(request.body.read())` will do . same as in your code. see the `print` statement